# I don't have the right answer in SQL

Tags: sql

List the project numbers (PR_NO) for projects that have only received parts that are stored in (P_CITY) the same city as the project (show output of the query).

Table: EMP 
Primary Key: E_NO

```
E_NO    E_NAME  E_RATE  E_DEPT
1          A    $400.00 
2          B    $200.00   1
3          C    $150.00   2
4          D    $150.00   3
5          E    $120.00   1
6          F    $100.00   1
7          G    $100.00   2
8          H    $50.00    2
9          I    $50.00    3
10         J    $50.00    3
11         K    $150.00   3
```

Table: PART
Primary Key: P_NO

```
P_NO    P_NAME  P_CITY
1         P1    NY
2         P2    NY
3         P3    LA
4         P4    SF
5         P5    LA
6         P6    NY
```

Table: PROJECT
Primary Key: PR_NO

```
PR_NO   PR_MGR  PR_DEPT PR_LOC
1           2         1     NY
2           3         2     LA
3           2         1     NY
```

Table: SUPPLIER
Primary Key: S_NO

```
S_NO    S_NAME  S_LOC
1          S1    NY
2          S2    NY
3          S3    LA
```

Table: SUPPLY

```
Primary Key: P_NO + PR_NO + S_NO
Foreign Key: P_NO references PART
Foreign Key: PR_NO references PROJECT
Foreign Key: S_NO references SUPPLIER

P_NO    PR_NO   S_NO    QTY
1          1    1       111
1          1    2       112
1          1    3       113
1          2    1       121
1          2    2       122
1          2    3       123
1          3    1       131
1          3    2       132
1          3    3       133
2          1    1       211
3          1    1       311
4          1    1       411
5          1    1       511
6          1    1       611
```

Table: WORK

```
Primary Key: E_NO + PR_NO
Foreign Key: E_NO references EMP
Foreign Key: PR_NO references PROJECT
E_NO    PR_NO   HRS
2          1    10
3          2    20
5          1    20
5          2    20
5          3    20
6          1    10
6          2    10



select distinct P.PR_NO
from PROJECT P, PART PA
where PA.P_CITY = P.PR_LOC;
```

The right answer question should be :

```
PR_NO
3
```

This is the error:

```
PR_NO
    1
    3
    2
```

Comment: Hint:  You need to `join` on two keys.

Comment: Please explain why you think the result should be `3` only.

Comment: "that have only received parts" - There should be a third table.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You've removed tables `Supplier` and `Supply` in your edit which seems important to me to achieve this task, even though OP's query doesn't mention those tables.

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved/helped you to solve your problem,kindly mark it as an answer and/or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this task, you also need to use `Supply` table as follows:

```
select s.pr_no
from supply s
inner join part p
on p.p_no = s.p_no
group by s.pr_no
having max(p.p_city) = min(p.p_city)
and    min(p.p_city) = (select pr_loc
                        from project
                        where pr_no = s.pr_no
                       )
```

Comment: Though that might work on some RDBMS, you should not access `p.p_city` in the HAVING clause, since it's not listed in GROUP BY. But you could work around that issue with something like `max(p.p_city) = ...`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel l want to check here that the supplied (received) parts must be from one location only. I agree with you. I should check that with `max(p.p_city) = min(p.p_city)`. Am I right?

Comment: Well.. we know that there can be only one city because of `count(distinct p.p_city) = 1` (your edit doesn't change anything). But the RDBMS is usually not that smart as we are ;-) - So it will complain not knowing where to read `p.p_city` (There are multiple rows in the group). But since we know, there can only be one city, we can just use `min()` or `max()` to avoid the error. So I mean that part: `and min(p.p_city) = (select pr_loc ...)`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Got it. Edited the query. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: It should also be `select s.pr_no` instead of `s.p_no`

Comment: To demonstrate the problem from my first comment - here is a [postgre fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9e83c/1). Remove the `min()` from the second condition and you will get an error: "column "p.p_city" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

Comment: Totally understood your point and that's why I modified the query. I hope it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your query is that you should correctly join the 2 tables PROJECT and PART before filtering; so in this case you should use the table SUPPLY.

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.PR_NO
  FROM SUPPLY S
  INNER JOIN PROJECT PR
  ON S.PR_NO = PR.PR_NO
  INNER JOIN PART P
  ON S.P_NO = P.P_NO
  WHERE PR.PR_LOC = P.P_CITY
  AND S.PR_NO NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT S.PR_NO
                         FROM SUPPLY S
                         INNER JOIN PROJECT PR
                         ON S.PR_NO = PR.PR_NO
                         INNER JOIN PART P
                         ON S.P_NO = P.P_NO
                         WHERE PR.PR_LOC <> P.P_CITY );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note the "only" in "that have **only** received parts that are stored in (P_CITY) the same city as the project".

Answer (score 0):

I tested this query with your example data and it returns project #3 as expected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.PR_NO
FROM
    SUPPLY S
    INNER JOIN PROJECT PR
        ON S.PR_NO = PR.PR_NO
    INNER JOIN PART P
        ON S.P_NO = P.P_NO
WHERE
    PR.PR_LOC = P.P_CITY AND
    NOT S.PR_NO IN
        (
            SELECT S2.PR_NO
            FROM
                SUPPLY S2
                INNER JOIN PROJECT PR2
                    ON S2.PR_NO = PR2.PR_NO
                INNER JOIN PART P2
                    ON S2.P_NO = P2.P_NO
            WHERE PR2.PR_LOC <> P2.P_CITY
        )
```

The SUPPLY table creates the link between PART and PROJECT. The main query looks for parts that are stored in the same city as the project. The sub-select in the where clause looks almost the same, except that it looks for parts stored in a different city. Projects with such cities are excluded with `NOT S.PR_NO IN (...)`.